# IE8 Iframe over entire body

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe that is the same size as an entire page. It is over the page with no problem, however when scrolling the iframe in IE 8 the body underneath the frame scrolls with the frame. You can also click elements underneath the frame as well.

How can I get the browser to target only the iframe when it is visible?

I have tried

```
popup.focus(); 
top.document.body.blur();
```

but those come up undefined in the IE8 console?

thanks

Comment: iframe on entire page... I don't want to live on this planet anymore

Comment: Do you want to hide the true URL or something... basically why would you do this

Comment: @mishik Be happy it's not an applet :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an iframe covering the rest, you could do two `div` elements, and make only one visible. You can still put the iframe in the second div, but the point is to make only one div visible at a time.